# Draw circle and vectors

Tags: tikz-pgf

I've plotted the following graph, using `tikz`:

[image: circle]

But I don't know how to make the vectors end exactly on the circle. Is there any simple way to do it?

**CODE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}% To get more advances positioning options
\usetikzlibrary{arrows}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[step=1cm,gray!25!,very thin] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[thick,->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) -- (2,2) node[midway,above] {$\vec{a}$};
\draw[thick,->] (-2,0) -- (2,2) node[midway, above] {$\vec{a'}$};
\draw[blue, thick,->] (-2,0) -- (0,0) node[midway, above] {$\Delta x$};
\draw[red, thick] (0,0) circle (2 cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You can use functions like cosine as coordinate x or y…

Comment: You could use polar coordinates, e.g. `(60:2)` instead of `(2,2)`.

Comment: I had a couple of comments, all very minor, so I added an answer. You can still decide to delete the question, I am not doing this for reputation. Yet  I do not think that everyone but you knows polar coordinates, so the question is OK IMHO.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use polar coordinates. And you do not need the libraries you are loading here, and in any case I would prefer `arrows.meta` over `arrows`. `mathtools` is not used either. And I would label repeating coordinates such that the diagram becomes easier to adjust.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\draw[step=1cm,gray!25!,very thin] (-5,-5) grid (5,5);
\draw[thick,->] (-3,0) -- (3,0) node[anchor=north west] {x axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,-3) -- (0,3) node[anchor=south east] {y axis};
\draw[thick,->] (0,0) coordinate (O) -- (50:2) coordinate (oc) 
node[midway,below] {$\vec{a}$};
\draw[thick,->] (-2,0) coordinate (L) -- (oc) node[midway, above] {$\vec{a'}$};
\draw[blue, thick,->] (L) -- (O) node[midway, above] {$\Delta x$};
\draw[red, thick] (O) circle (2 cm);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to write an short arrow above the circle to give the positive orientation? the -> added to the draw circle doesn't work for that.

Comment: @pzorba75 No, it doesn't. Depending on where you want to have the arrow try `\draw[red, thick,->] (<angle>:2) arc(<angle>:<angle>+360:2);`, where `<angle>` is the angle you want to have the arrow at. IMHO the result looks better if you use the `bending` library for that, but spelling this out in detail goes beyond the space of a comment.